# Avoid System.IO.IOException exception when accessing SQLite file in 2 programs

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am writing to c# programs 1 a service and the other a GUI application to monitor activities in a service. I don't know whether this is just a Windows thing that once I open the file in `DB Browser for SQLite` I get the following exception when I try to open the file in my service;

```
System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file '...\database.db' because it is being used by another process.'
```

It works fine when I open the file first in my app and then in the `DB Browser for SQLite` program and I can see the tables and records being created. So I am wondering whether there is a way to avoid this exception in my code maybe by using opening flags. I am using the c# library [praeclarum/sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) (SQLite-net PCL)

My code looks like this to open the file;

```
class SQLiteDb
    {
        private string databaseDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "AttorneyScraper");
        private string databasePath;
        public SQLiteAsyncConnection db;

        public SQLiteDb()
        {
            databasePath = Path.Combine(databaseDirectory, "database.db");
            if (!Directory.Exists(databaseDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(databaseDirectory);
            }
            System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(databasePath);
            db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(databasePath);
            ...
```

I see there is another overload that accepts an openFlag;

```
public SQLiteAsyncConnection(string databasePath, SQLiteOpenFlags openFlags, bool storeDateTimeAsTicks = true);
```

This `SQLiteOpenFlags` enum looks like this;

```
public enum SQLiteOpenFlags
{
    ReadOnly = 1,
    ReadWrite = 2,
    Create = 4,
    NoMutex = 32768,
    FullMutex = 65536,
    SharedCache = 131072,
    PrivateCache = 262144,
    ProtectionComplete = 1048576,
    ProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen = 2097152,
    ProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication = 3145728,
    ProtectionNone = 4194304
}
```

I know that SQLite allows to access a file in 2 programs from research.

Comment: Why do you call `SQLiteConnection.CreateFile`?

Comment: Just in case the file does not exist. It will have to be created automatically.

Comment: Unless you pass `FailIfMissing` in connection string, file will be created automatically.

Comment: Using `db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(databasePath);` The file is never created. I get an exception about unable to open file. So it looks like I have to create it first with `System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(databasePath);` if it does not exist

Comment: Okay, I see. `System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(databasePath);` is causing the exception. So using `if (!File.Exists(databasePath))` solves the problem. So no attempt is done to try and create the file. The `System.IO.IOException` occurs when trying to create the file when other programs are using it.